# Display UTC time in Angular

Tags: angular, timezone, angular-pipe, angular-date-format

I currently get the following UTC date from my web API.
**"2018-04-05T11:50:37.6173487Z"**

I wanted to display it as such **05.04.18 11:50 UTC**
However, using {{ResponseTime| date:'dd.MM.yy HH:mm'}} id displaying **05.04.18 13:50**. It seems that the pipe automatically converts the date to my timezone which is UTC+2. How should I do to display my date in the UTC timezone?

Answer (score -1):

Use Date Pipe!

import the following

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

Declare in the constructure as well

```
 constructor( private datePipe: DatePipe ) {}
```

then use like this

```
var example = this.datePipe.transform(Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

you can use any format you need or if you have a date string you can replace the Date() and will do the same

```
var date = "01/01/2018";
var example2 = this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

Good luck!